# Convert a character Column in a data.table to bigz Integer

Tags: r, data.table, gmp

I am working with a `data.table` that has been read in from a .txt file with `fread`. The `data.table` contains some amount of `integer` columns as well as a column of very large integers that I intend to store as `bigz`. However, `fread` will only read in large integers as `character` if I plan on keeping all of the digits (and I do).

```
#Something to the effect of (run not needed):
#fread(file = FILENAME.txt, header=TRUE, colClasses = c(rep("integer", 10), "character"), data.table = TRUE)
```

Additionally, I am working with a fairly large dataset. My primary problem is converting a `character` column in a `data.table` to a `bigz` column ***without creating a new object.***

Here's a toy example which demonstrates my issue. First, I know that `data.table`s *can* have `bigz`columns - *IF* they are introduced in a new object.

```
library(gmp)
library(data.table)
exa = as.bigz(2)^80          #A very large number          
cha = as.character(exa)      #The same number in character form
(good = data.table(nums = 1:3, lets = letters[1:3], bigs = rep(exa, 3)))   
str(good)                    #Notice "bigs" is type bigz (and raw?)
```

However, if a `character` column is to be converted to a `bigz` column on the fly, an error results. The syntax in these conversion methods "works" w.r.t. the `numeric` `nums` column if `as.bigz` is replaced with `as.character`.

```
(bad = data.table(nums = 1:3, lets = letters[1:3], bigs = rep(cha, 3)))
str(bad)
#Method 1
bad[,bigs:=as.bigz(bigs)]
#Method 2 (re-create data.table first)
bad = data.table(nums = 1:3, lets = letters[1:3], bigs = rep(cha, 3))
set(bad, j="bigs", value = as.bigz(bad$bigs))
```

Error below. It appears that the issue stems from `bigz` integers being stored as `raw`, although I am not sure where '64' is coming from - `exa` has 24 digits.

```
Warning messages:
1: In `[.data.table`(bad, , `:=`(bigs, as.bigz(bigs))) :
Supplied 64 items to be assigned to 3 items of column 'bigs' (61 unused)
2: In `[.data.table`(bad, , `:=`(bigs, as.bigz(bigs))) :
Coerced 'raw' RHS to 'character' to match the column's type. Either change the target column ['bigs'] to 'raw' first (by creating a new 'raw' vector length 3 (nrows of entire table) and assign that; i.e. 'replace' column), or coerce RHS to 'character' (e.g. 1L, NA_[real|integer]_, as.*, etc) to make your intent clear and for speed. Or, set the column type correctly up front when you create the table and stick to it, please.
```

I have a work-around for now, but it requires creating a new object (and deleting the old one).

```
(bad = data.table(nums = 1:3, lets = letters[1:3], bigs = rep(cha, 3)))
meh = data.table(as.data.frame(bad)[,-3], bigs = as.bigz(bad$bigs))
rm(bad)
str(meh)
identical(good, meh)          #Well, at least this works
```

I think this situation could be resolved if:

1. `fread` could read in `bigz` integers, or
2. there is a way to change the column type without creating a new object.

Admittedly, I am a `data.table` novice. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The length 64 is the length of the raw vector (used for storing the bigz numbers), the first four bytes are used to denote the length of the vector (according to bigz), then there is twenty bytes (this is variable though) for each number.

Comment: Your best bet is to have all of your large numbers stored in a matrix or a list of vectors. Once you've done all of your computation, convert to a `character` and add them back to your data frame. The `gmp` library comes equipped with a matrix class that is able to handle `bigz` types.

Comment: I'm also reminded that the `gmp` library works with character data type as well, so I don't see the need to have a field class explicitly be `bigz`. For example, you can do stuff like : `bad$bigsSquared <- as.character(pow.bigz(bad$bigs, 2))`

Answer (score 1):

These `bigq` numbers seem to be a pain to work with. Additionally, it seems they cannot be held as the only column in a `data.table`.

The only work around I can find is to declare a new `data.table` which is what you have already done, only it can be done more succinctly without creating a new object.

```
library(gmp)
library(data.table)

exa = as.bigz(2)^80          #A very large number          
cha = as.character(exa)
bad = data.table(nums = 1:3, lets = letters[1:3], bigs = rep(cha, 3))
bad = data.table(bad,bigsN = as.bigz(bad$bigs))
str(bad)
```

However, these columns cannot be  manipulated inside the `data.table` without the same problems.

```
bad$bigsN = bad$bigsN*2
## Error in `[<-.data.table`(x, j = name, value = value) : 
##   Unsupported type 'raw'
## In addition: Warning message:
## In `[<-.data.table`(x, j = name, value = value) :
##   Supplied 64 items to be assigned to 3 items of column 'bigsN' (61 unused)
```

The best solution I can think of is simply to keep these objects as separate vectors to your `data.table`.

### as.list

Another solution would be to embed the the `bigz` in a list.

```
library(gmp)
library(data.table)

exa = as.bigz(2)^80          #A very large number          
cha = as.character(exa)
bad = data.table(nums = 1:3, lets = letters[1:3], bigs = rep(cha, 3))
bad = bad[,bigs := as.list(as.bigz(bad$bigs))]
```

This gives R a better handle on the location of elements, and is more memory efficient at the creation stage. The down side is each element is a length 1 `bigz` vector and as such holds 4 redundant bytes of data per element. It also still cannot be used for arithmetic in a vectorised fashion.

```
 bad$bigs = bad$bigs * 2
## Error in bad$bigs * 2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
 bad$bigs[[2]] = bad$bigs[[2]] * 2
 bad$bigs
## [[1]]
## Big Integer ('bigz') :
## [1] 1208925819614629174706176
## 
## [[2]]
## Big Integer ('bigz') :
## [1] 2417851639229258349412352
## 
## [[3]]
## Big Integer ('bigz') :
## [1] 1208925819614629174706176
```

In fact, it would seem very little can be done with it in a vetorised fashion, including sorting or even converting it back into a `bigz` vector.

Comment: Your line doesn't require an `rm` statement, but it still creates a new object in memory and doesn't remove the redundant `character` column.
`meh = data.table(as.data.frame(bad)[,-3], bigs = as.bigz(bad$bigs))`
`bad = data.table(bad,bigsN = as.bigz(bad$bigs))`
My prior code treated the `bigz` column as a separate vector. I ran into issues when subsetting the `bigz` vector by row conditions in the `data.table`. 1) It required careful sorting, and 2) I was using clumsy `rowname` statements to pull corresponding values. I subset a ~200K row `data.table` ~1M times, too.

Comment: What do you actually want to use the numbers for? Will you be doing arithmetic or just using them for sorting? If you need to do arithmetic, Then allocating these numbers to a `data.table` will continue to cause headaches. If it is just for sorting, then it might be better to use sub-strings to add several integer columns. These columns will work seamlessly with the `data.table` and have (assuming you numbers are generally of a similar order of magnitude) a similar memory requirement to the `bigz` type.

Comment: This seems to have gone beyond the scope of the original question. I already have a stand-alone `bigz` vector solution; I am exploring "the `data.table` way". In *my* case, the `bigz` integers range from ~10^14 to ~10^45, and they take up roughly half the space if they're in a `data.table` as compared to a stand-alone vector.

The point that you're missing is that the `data.table` and `gmp` packages don't seem to work well together. I already have a work-around (in OP), but it shouldn't have to be like that... and it might not be - I'd like to get responses from other people.

Comment: I fully appreciate that these two don't work well together, which is why my suggestions are generally to avoid mixing them. The trouble with `bigz` I expect comes down to referencing. You cannot look at a vector and know where the nth element is (in memory) because each element is of variable length; as such to access the nth element you need to check the length of each of the n-1 preceding elements. This same logic should apply to character but I am unsure about the internal working of in how is stores and references character vectors. That said, I think of another imperfect solution.